# Sharepoint search error without correlation ID

Tags: search

I've had a dig around the site and lots of googling to see if I can find anything regarding this but haven't been able to yet. Currently, a default sharepoint site is set up which has had a full crawl performed on. Searching on this default site works as expected, bringing back all the necessary results.

However, any other site set up as the external/internal/internet zone errors when trying to search. A sharepoint error is thrown but clicking more details does not provide me with a sharepoint correlation ID so I'm not sure where to start in terms of finding the issue.

[image]

Anyone got any ideas or run into the same issue before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This usually isn't a problem, but you should verify that your crawl account has minimum access to the extended zone.  If you've used a different application pool service account for the new zone, you should also check that the application pool service account has the appropriate permissions to search.

Answer (score 0):

This happens in certain scenarios with search errors. You can still retrieve the correlation ID because [SharePoint gives you the correlation ID in the SPRequestGuid field in the HTTP response header](http://jasonwarren.ca/sprequestguid/).

Open the developer console in your browser and go to the Network tab. In some browsers like IE make sure it has started to collect information (i.e. press the Play button or triangle if you see one).

Reload the page, and wait until it's done loading (hopefully with the error). In the list will be all the resources the browser loaded, including the page you requested, JavaScript, CSS, and image files. Select the page you were accessing (i.e. the one that matches the URL in your address bar) and there will be a tab called Headers or something to that effect. Under Response Headers, look for SPRequestGuid. The GUID there is the correlation ID, which you can then use as you normally would with [Merge-SPLogFile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ff607721.aspx) or whatever method you use for combing through your ULS logs.